# Passing objects created by new[] to a class, destructor for deletion necessary?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

I don't know if I should create a destructor to delete the members of `Controller` that are set to the parameters passed by main which are created dynamically, because the constructor never used the `new` keyword to set them.

```
int main()  
{
    int numCars = 3;
    int numPlanes = 3;
    Machine *car= new Car[numCars];
    Machine *plane = new Plane[numPlanes];

    Controller *control = new Controller(car, plane);

    delete control;
    return 0;
}

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller(Machine *car, Machine *plane);
//Would I need to make a destructor 
//~Controller();
private:
    Machine *car;
    Machine *plane;
Controller :: Controller(Machine *car, Machine *plane)
{
    this->car = car;
    this->plane = plane;
    changeCarandPlane();
}
//destructor
//    Controller :: ~Controller()
//   {
//    delete[] car;
//    delete[] plane;
//    }
};
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Go read something about RAII, ownership semanthic and proper memory management paradigms.

Comment: All you need to know about memory management: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you shouldn't delete in the destructor. `main` seems to own the allocated arrays, so delete from `main`.

```
int main()  
{
    int numCars = 3;
    int numPlanes = 3;
    Machine *car= new Car[numCars];
    Machine *plane = new Plane[numPlanes];

    Controller *control = new Controller(car, plane);

    delete control;
    delete [] plane;
    delete [] car;
    return 0;
}
```

If you were to delete in the `Controller` destructor, you would have to ensure that no two instances of `Controller` point to the same dynamically allocated `Machine` arrays.

You should consider using `std::vector<Machine>` instead of dynamically allocated arrays, or at least some scope guards to guarantee deletion.

```
#include <vector>
int main()  
{
    const int numCars = 3;
    const int numPlanes = 3;
    std::vector<Machine> cars(numCars); // holds 3 default constructed Machines
    std::vector<Machine> planes(numPlanes); // holds 3 default constructed Machines

    Controller control(cars, planes);
}
```

Comment: thank you, however my professor forbids us to use any STL data structure classes, unless there's something more than dynamic arrays, I'm stuck with them.

Comment: @Dog then you just have to delete them as in my first code sample, or wrap them in a scope guard to make sure they get deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In good design usually the entity that created the object is also responsible for freeing it. Given that, either free your memory from `main()` or allocate in the controller constructor and free in the controller destructor - the choice depends on the actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

How about using shared pointers then?

```
#include <memory>

class Machine {};
class Car : public Machine{};
class Plane : public Machine{};

template<typename T>
struct ArrayDeleter
{
   void operator()(T* p)
   {
      delete [] p;
   }
};

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller(std::shared_ptr<Car> cars, std::shared_ptr<Plane> planes)
    {}
};

int main()  
{
    int numCars = 3;
    int numPlanes = 3;
    std::shared_ptr<Car> cars(new Car[numCars], ArrayDeleter<Car>());
    std::shared_ptr<Plane> planes(new Plane[numPlanes], ArrayDeleter<Plane>());

    Controller *control = new Controller(cars, planes);

    delete control;
    return 0;
}
```